# Invocation of script function results in "Range not found" for composite ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a script that has been running for a while now, and suddenly it stopped working. The function basically counts the number of cells in a certain range with the same background color as a given cell. The script method is relatively simple:

```js
function countOnBGColor(sheetName, givenRange, colorref, dummyParam) {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var color = sheet.getRange(colorref).getBackground();
    var range = sheet.getRange(givenRange);
    var rangeVal = range.getValues();
    var count = 0;
    var allColors = range.getBackgrounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < allColors.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < allColors[0].length; j++) {
            if (allColors[i][j] == color) count += 1;
        };
    };
    return count;
}
```

The dummy param being used to retrigger the execution of the script. It is invoked from a sheet using, for example following statement:

```
=countOnBGColor($C$6;$C$5;TEKST.SAMENVOEGEN($C$9;RIJ()+$C$10-$C$11); $C$2)
```

Here, the most important parameter is C$5$ whose value itself is the result of a computation. However, the value after computation is usually something as `{C5:O11;C16:J21}` and if I hardcode this value in cell $C$5 for the second parameter, the result is the same.

The execution of the function results in:

> Exception: Range not Found

If I change the hardcoded value in cell `$C$5` into, for example,  `C5:O11` the method returns without problem. So the problem only occurs if I pass two separate ranges in the array notation.

I haven't changed that script in ages, and it used to work. Any reason why the function no longer works with a composite range such as `{C5:O11;C16:K21}` but does with a simple range such as `C5:O11`?

Comment: Where did you get the impression that getRange() will work with two ranges in A1Notation separated by a semi colon. How does dummpyParam retrigger the execution of the script

Comment: I got the impression from the fact that it used to work, and personally, I feel it would be logical if it did: in the sheet all operations that operate on a range work regardless if it is a single or composite range. Of course, that is irrelevant :). After reading your responses, I now see that apparantly it doesn't, and investigated why it did. It was probably because the computation that generated the range used to return a single range instead. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: In practice, most of the input fields for the method refer to cells which are not changed by user behavior (for example, dependent on dates). So I need a reference to a cell with a value I can just change in order to trigger the invocation of the method. It has nothing to do with the method itself.

Comment: Are you using the function as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en#getting_started)?

Comment: By the way, the suggestion to replace getRange() by getRangeList() is flawed because getRangeList returns a RangeList which requires the getRanges() method to return the actual ranges.  i.e. it's not the same kind of object.

Answer (score 1):

**The `getRange(a1Notation)` method will always expect a *single range* in the A1 notation.**

If you want to retrieve multiple ranges, the method you should choose is `getRangeList(a1Notations)`:

```
sheet.getRangeList(['C5:O11', 'C16:K21']);
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations).